# c++ finding same record in vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, asymptotic-complexity, word-count

Ihave a vector that contains monthyear

Jan2013 
Jan2013
Jan2013
Jan2014 
Jan2014
Jan2014
Jan2014
Feb2014
Feb2014

Basically what I want to do is to search through the vector, for every same record, group them
together like 
e.g

```
total count for Jan2013 = 3; 
total count for Jan2014 = 4; 
total count for Feb2014 = 2;
```

Of course as we know, we can just simply write multiple if to solve it

```
        if(monthyear = "Jan2013")  {
            //add count   
        }

        if(monthyear = "Jan2014")  {
            //add count   
        }

        if(monthyear = "Feb2014")  {
            //add count   
        }
```

but no way a programmer is going code it in this way.
what if there's additional monthyear march2014,april2014,may2014 all the way to dec2014
and jan2015-dec2015 and so on.

I don't think I should be adopting this kind of hard-coding method in the
long run and looking for a more dynamic approach.

I not asking for codes, but just some steps and perhaps give me some hints on what c++ methods should I be researching on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be sure to use `monthyear == "...2014"` in your if statements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `std::map`. For example

```
std::map<std::string, size_t> m;

for ( const std::string &s : v ) ++m[s];
```

Comment: Here is an example

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>


int main() 
{
 std::vector<std::string> v = 
 { 
  "Jan2013", "Jan2013", "Jan2013",
  "Jan2014", "Jan2014", "Jan2014", "Jan2014",
  "Feb2014", "Feb2014"
 };
 
 std::map<std::string, size_t> m;
 
 for ( const std::string &s : v ) ++m[s];
 
 for ( auto p : m ) std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
 
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably do a `std::map<monthyear, int>`. For each member of your vector, increment that member of the map.

Comment: @user2947249: Vlad from Moscow gave you a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: the solution by @VladfromMoscow is optimal for the general case in which you have little knowledge about your input. It is of `O(N log N)` complexity for an input of length `N`.

Equivalently, you can first sort your input in `O(N log N)`, and then iterate in `O(N)` over the sorted input and store the counts in a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>`.

However, if you have *a priori* information on the range of your input (say you *know for sure* it runs from Jan 2013 until Jan 2014), you can also directly run over your input and update a pre-allocated `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>` in `O(N)` complexity.